# Stop RadioButtonList posback on client validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I am trying to prevent a radio button list from posting back if there is an error but it still posts back. Not sure what i am doing wrong! When selection is changed, I check the selection in a drop down list and if nothing is selected, I display error ("Please select blah from drop down") and return false.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" 
    ID="rblCoverType" 
    ClientIDMode="Static" 
    DataSourceID="odsSwapTypes" 
    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
    RepeatLayout="Flow" 
    AutoPostBack="true" 
    DataTextField="SwapType" 
    DataValueField="SwapTypeID"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblCoverType_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<span id="lblErrCoverType" class="field-validation-error pull-left" style="display: inline"></span>

$(document).on('change', '#rblCoverType', function () {
    debugger
    var isValid = true;

    // Check the value in drop down list
    var swapScheduleWeekStart = $("#ddlSwapSheduledWeeks option:selected").val().trim();

        if (swapScheduleWeekStart == "") {
            // Clear radio button list selection, display error
            $("#rblCoverType").prop('checked',false);
            $("#lblErrCoverType").val('Some error msg here');
            $("#lblErrCoverType").show();
            isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
});
```

I tried using "onChange" client side event for radio button list, didn't get hit at all.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this easily. Aspnet generates the following html

```
<span id="rblCoverType">
    <input id="rblCoverType_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$mainContentPane$rblCoverType" value="Value 1" 
       onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$mainContentPane$rblCoverType$rblCoverType_0\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" />
```

Note that the click event is set to the `input` control inline. So if you really want to prevent that `onclick` you would have to add and remove it manually. I might be easier to lose the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` and do everything client side.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#rblCoverType input")[0].onclick = null;
        $("#rblCoverType input").click(function () {
            alert("Clicked");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This gave me an idea (not sure if right or not) but I removed autopostback='true' and onselectedindechanged, and on client side if it validated I manually did a postback. Seems to (partially) work but does not display error or clear radio button selection on error since radio button list is in an update panel :(. To update update panel, it seems I have to do a postback, even in case of error, which defeats the purpose.